# Draw a plot of glyphs in Matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, glyph

I was using **Matplotlib** to plot some scientific visualizations for which heat map plots (as the one below) was sufficient. My code is all written in **Python** too.

[image]

However, now I need to present a more "elaborated" plot, which consists of glyphs. The following image (the second one) shows an example:

[image]

In that image, each point of the plot is a glyph that represents a probability of a vector field orientation. This is glyph is draw as a circle with a main direction and a standard deviation from its direction.

I would like to do something similar. My idea was to draw something like a polar histogram at each position and to have a plot comprised by polar charts. However, I don't think that is possible with Matplotlib; at least I don't have any idea how this can be done. As my whole code is written in Python, I was wondering if somehow I can stand with Matplotlib, or if I should study how to do this with OpenGL or another API/libraty.

Thank you.

Comment: I can't understand your problem from your problem description and the image you posted. It may be be, it may be that you didn't spend enough effort in exactly explaining what you want...

Comment: I'd go with Wedges instead of histograms -- http://matplotlib.org/api/patches_api.html?highlight=patch#matplotlib.patches.Wedge

Comment: & possibly storing defined glyphs in the.... three-dimensional? space that defines them, since it looks like you reuse them (at least, within what a reader can actually tell apart). Big ol' dictionary or something of your glyphs.

Comment: Not storing them, it turns out, as a Wedge is defined partly by its location.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps a whole lot of something like this:

[image]

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from matplotlib.collections import PatchCollection
from matplotlib.patches import Wedge, Circle
from math import degrees, pi

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
wedges = []
circles = []

for x in np.arange(0, 3.3, .3):
    for y in np.arange(0, 3.3, .3):
        theta, phi = np.random.random(2)  # functions of (x,y) in reality
        for v in (0, pi):
            wedges.append(Wedge((x, y),
                            .15,
                            degrees(v - phi - theta/2),
                            degrees(v - phi + theta/2),
                            edgecolor='none'),
                            )
        circles.append(Circle((x, y),
                             .15,
                             edgecolor='none'))


colors = np.linspace(0, 1, len(circles))  # function of (x,y) in reality
collection = PatchCollection(circles, cmap=plt.cm.jet, alpha=0.2)
collection.set_array(np.array(colors))
collection.set_edgecolor('none')
ax.add_collection(collection)

#wedgecolors = list(chain.from_iterable(repeat(i,2) for i in colors))
wedgecolors = np.array([colors, colors]).flatten('F') # no itertools
collection = PatchCollection(wedges, cmap=plt.cm.jet, alpha=1)
collection.set_array(np.array(wedgecolors))
collection.set_edgecolor('none')
ax.add_collection(collection)

ax.set_xlim(0,3)
ax.set_ylim(0,3)
ax.set_aspect('equal')
plt.show()
```

(Setting the edgecolor has to be done (redone?) after the `collection.set_array` call, apparently.)

Comment: Hi, @cphlewis. I'm receiving an error when running your code. After importing the itertools module, I get "Exception in Tkinter callback". Don't know what it is. Thank you.

Comment: I don't use Tkinter, don't know... have put in an alternative that only uses numpy. Probably you should isolate the new problem and post it as an issue for the Tk/itertools tag.